# Python 3 Timed If, Then, Else Statement

Tags: python-3.x, timer

I am working on a game in Python 3 and I am having trouble with a bit of code. What I want to do is to have a timer running in the background. The player would input an answer on what to do. If the player answered before the timer ended, then the timer would stop. If the player did not give an answer before the timer ended, then they would lose. I am thinking of three possible courses of action after this other than the timer running out and the game ending. If you got your information from a source other than yourself please leave a link to the source. All replies are appreciated.
EDIT: The closest comparison I can make for this is a quick time event in video games.

Comment: That sounds like a plan: write it. (In a simple/normal console application there is not an intrinsic notion of a 'background timer', but the program can definitely record the time the question was asked and compare against the time it was answered.)

Comment: Ref. https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time

Answer (score 0):

You want to wait until one of two events occur: user enters an answer, or timeout expires.  In the absence of input() having a timeout argument, this is most easily done with tkinter.  Here is a minimal example.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def timeout_cb():
    answer.unbind('<Key-Return>')  # disable answer entry
    print('timed out')

def answer_cb(event):
    root.after_cancel(time_id)  # disable timeout timer
    print('you answered', answer.get())

prompt = tk.Label(root, text='Name?')
answer = tk.Entry(root)
prompt.grid(row=0, column=0)
answer.grid(row=0, column=1)
answer.focus_set()
answer.bind('<Key-Return>', answer_cb)
time_id = root.after(10000, timeout_cb)  # 10 seconds

root.mainloop()
```

In practice, you would replace the print statements with whatever you want to do next.  You could also add a countdown label with the time left to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll let you know how it goes afterwards.